# Getting Size of Struct That Contains Dynamically Allocated Memory

Tags: c, memory-management

I would like to allocate memory for a buffer that will contain, via memcpy in the future, a struct that contains a pointer that has been previously dynamically allocated memory.

That is, I have a struct

```
struct test_struct {
    int   num;
    char  *values;
};
```

Where `test_struct.values` contains `num` amount of strings of length `LENGTH`.  I know I can't get the size of memory a pointer has been allocated, so I just keep track of it via `num`.  What is the easiest/cleanest way of getting the size of this struct?

The only solution I can come up with is something like

`buf = malloc(sizeof(test_struct) + (num * LENGTH));`

But I'm new to this low-level memory management stuff, so there might be something better.

Comment: the size of that struct is constant

Comment: The size of the struct never changes, it's just `sizeof(test_struct)`.  If you want to know the total memory allocated, then yes you'll need to do `num * sizeof(*values)` as well.

Comment: @Taylor Correct.  However, the buffer that will contain it has to be allocated enough memory to hold `values`.  Which is why I compute how big `values` is with `num*LENGTH`, then add size of the `struct` itself.

Comment: @justynnuff: In that case, I'm not sure what your question is?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I worded this question pretty poorly, I suppose.  I should have added I have a buffer `char *buf;`, and a struct `struct test_struct t_struct;`.  What's the best/cleanest way to figure out the size of memory to `malloc` for buf in order to do a `memcpy(&buf, &t_struct, ???);`

Comment: @justynnuff I edited my answer to reflect your request.

Comment: @justynnuff if you want to memcpy from &buf you show us where buf is coming from. It can make a big difference if buff is not another test_struct

Comment: `memcpy` will never work since it will not update the pointer in the copy to point to the copied values. The pointer will still point to the original values. You need to do the copy manually.

Comment: @Taylor Please read the comment above yours.  buf is a char *.  The first argument of `memcpy` is the destination.  I'm copying TO `buf`.

Comment: @justynnuff I just did and updated my answer. I would advise against using memcpy in your case, it's very impractical for copying this kind of struct.

Comment: @TaylorFlores I see now.  I'm just plain wrong.  What I would like to do is send that struct via a UDP multicast packet using sendto().  Can you advise how I can accomplish that?  I've already done something similar successfully, but instead of just a pointer in my struct, I had arrays...ie, I just memcpy'ed my struct to a buffer, then sent the buffer via sendo().

Comment: I would just avoid memcpy altogether and just send a string per packet by traversing the structure (in the way that I have done in my answer). If the order of the strings is important (and you're using UDP) then you can memcpy into the new buffer but just replace the first nine null-terminators with a space (ascii space = 32). Are you going to send struct_t.num as well?

Comment: I would like to send everything, yes.  I expected to be able to memcpy to a char * buffer, then receive the buffer, and memcpy back to the struct in order to read each field on the other end.  Again, it works for the case in which the pointer is an array at first.  But I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer. It might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to memcpy two structs then the memory in both of them must be continuous. But you would have to determine `num` beforehand.

```
struct test_struct {
    int num;
    char ** values;
} * TestStruct;

int _num = 0;

// find _num

TestStruct = malloc (sizeof (struct test_struct) + (sizeof(char*) * _num) + (LENGTH * _num));

TestStruct->num = _num;
TestStruct->values = &TestStruct + sizeof (struct test_struct);

for (int i = 0; i < _num; i++){
    TestStruct->values[i] = &TestStruct + sizeof (struct test_struct) + (i * LENGTH);
}
```

The reason I changed char * to char ** is because using char * it becomes harder to access the strings after the first (I'm assuming they're null terminated). Also, after calling memcpy, you must update all the string pointers in the new struct.

To memcpy you would do this:

```
memcpy (buf, TestStruct->values[0], LENGTH * TestStruct->num);
```

But in buf, however, you would only see the first string (unless your strings are not null-terminated). You would have to increment the pointer after every null terminated character until you know, with `num`, that you've reached the end of the buffer.

---

Now that I understand more of the context of your request, consider the following.

If you're using UDP packets, you should send the data in one packet so that it arrives in the order you expect. When more than one packet is sent, it may arrive out of order. <strike>Because of this, you need to make sure the size of the data is <= 512 bytes - which is the maximum size of a UDP packet.</strike> Also, you need to make sure all the data is in contiguous memory. I'm going to assume you have your data already in the struct you've provided in this example:

```
// this function puts the struct in contiguous memory

int PrepareBuffer (struct test_struct TestStruct, char ** buffer){

    char * cast = (char *) &TestStruct->num;

    * buffer = malloc ((TestStruct->num * LENGTH) + sizeof (int));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (int); i++) *buffer[i] = cast[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < (TestStruct->num * LENGTH); i++) *buffer[i + sizeof (int)] = TestStruct->values[i];
    return 0;
}
```

You will have to implement another function on the receiving end that maps the buffer to `struct test_struct`. Also, I have omitted error checking for clarity. You should check for how big the packet is going to be before to allocate memory <strike>(it has to be <= 512)</strike>. You should also check to make sure malloc returns a none-null pointer.

Comment: a pointer is 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine and the int is probably 4. it was just a guess, and may or may not be accurate

Comment: yeah, it also depends on what the compiler is doing. Even on a 64 bit computer, there may still be 32 bit pointers if that is requested at compile time.

Comment: Using sizeof is better than guesstimating size and alignment anyway. On a 64 bit machine, the structure could be 16 bytes long rather than 12, because of alignment.

Comment: @TaylorFlores By the way, from what I understand, a UDP packet has to be <512 bytes in order to avoid fragmentation.  However, the length of a UDP packet can be up to 2^16 - 1 (65535) bytes, as defined by the number of bits in the length field of the header.  Fragmented packets will be reassembled at the network layer, so it sounds like if there's a fragment missing, the entire packet is discarded.

Comment: Oh, didn't know! I guess you can disregard that part

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to allocate 4 bytes (for the integer on 32 bit linux) and 4 bytes for the char * (in 32 bit.  64 is 8).

What you're really asking though, is how do I know how much memory I need to allocate to the region pointed to by char *value.  You figure this out in the wya you're doing.  Then set value to the location of buf.  There's a comment blow me that is the correct way if you have multiple string, and you don't want to just jam them all together in that region and have to figure out which is which yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to allocate memory for both the structure and the buffer that values points to. If so, this is correct. To point at the extra space, do `buf->values = buf + 1;` (this is assuming you declare buf as `struct test_struct buf;`

Comment: this answer is from a while ago, but just to clarify `buf->values = buf + 1` does not point to extra space, it points to an offset byte of `buf->num` within the struct, which will overflow into `buf->values`. I think what you mean to write was `buf->values = &buf->values + sizeof (char*);`

Comment: I do not. In C, adding 1 to a pointer to struct x adds sizeof (struct x), not 1. If you add 1 to a char pointer, you do indeed add 1. Add 1 to a 32-bit integer pointer and you will actually add 4!

Comment: ah, I've encountered that in C++, but I didn't know it started in C.